# JPA ng-repeat filer - Multiple id's as one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

At the moment I have joined 2 tables. And it prints code like this:

```
1
    7
1
    8
1
    9
2
2
3
4
5
5
6
```

I am using angularjs ng-repeat to do what.
My goal is to make menu bar look like:

```
1
    7
    8
    9
2
3
4
5
6
```

My code:

```
<div id="menuList">
    <ul class="menuNav">
        <li class="menuList_Slide" ng-repeat="x in names">
            <div>               
                <a href="category.html?categoryid={{x.parentid}}" target="_self">{{x.parentid}}</a>
            </div>

            <div>
                <ul id="subCategories" ng-if="target == x.parentid">
                    <li>
                        <a href="category.html?subcategoryid={{x.id}}" target="_self">{{x.childid}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use ng-repeat filter to do what?

Comment: map your data to have the proper nesting within the data structure. Show data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could solve your problem by putting `ng-if` and checking for the last element which is the same or not like doing `ng-if="names[$index-1].parentid != x.parentid"`

**Markup**

```
<div id="menuList">
    <ul class="menuNav">
        <li class="menuList_Slide" ng-repeat="x in names">
            <div ng-if="names[$index-1].parentid != x.parentid">
                <a href="category.html?categoryid={{x.parentid}}" target="_self">{{x.parentid}}</a>
            </div>

            <div>
                <ul id="subCategories" ng-if="target == x.parentid">
                    <li>
                        <a href="category.html?subcategoryid={{x.id}}" target="_self">{{x.childid}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Laurynas Glad to help you.. Thanks :)